# How to get notifications from GET request Swift

Tags: swift, http, get, notifications

So, in my project I make a GET request that returns all the images that the user has. I want to notify the user once they receive a new image. 
What I could do is sent a timer with an interval and keep calling the Get request till I detect a new image. But I know this is not optimal and would like to know what the best practice is. 
Is there a way to set some kind of observer to HTTP requests in Swift? 
Thanks!

Comment: 1. This will only work if the app is in the foreground.
2. This approach will consume battery due to constant web calls.

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Do it on the server and use push notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more one way to do this. I would suggest you do the "you have a new image" detection on the server and use push notifications to notify the user.  This will offload the burden of doing all the checking from the app and will be optimal use of bandwidth, battery and computing resources.